# Select is invalid inside include operation for EF Core query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, migration

The project that I work on has a generic repository implementation approach for the data access and unfortunately, I cannot change it for now. Still, for now I need to migrate the project to .NET 6 and with that it will also use Entity Framework Core.

Because of that change, all **selects** used for the `includeProperties` now will throw the following error:

> The expression 'a.Appointment.Finance.AsQueryable().Select(fa =>
> fa.FinanceCompany)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it
> does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target
> navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by
> composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take
> operations.

The implementation is below, if anyone ever encountered this issue before I would highly appreciate any insights. I am kind of new and inexperienced using Entity Framework and this is giving me big headaches. If there was the possibility to give up on the generic repository implementation it would have been much better, but I can't do that.

```
using System.Linq;

// basic method to retrieve an appointment along its navigation properties
private readonly GenericRepository<Appointment> _repository;
{
    var appointment = _repository.Get(

           /*
            * Filter
            */
           a => a.AppointmentId == appointmentId,

           /*
            * Order By
            */
           null,

           /*
            * Includes
            */
           a => a.Purchases,
           a => a.Employee,
           a => a.Reviews,

           a => a.Appointment.Finance.Select(fa => fa.FinanceCompany), // problem here
       )
       .FirstOrDefaultReadUncommitted();
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Thank you for the time!

Comment: EF core uses `Include` and `ThenInclude` which makes it harder to add Includes as parameters. But, frankly, I don't understand this `Get` method. If you use LINQ directly where you call `Get` you can do anything you want.

Comment: A new take on an old bit of wisdom: 
Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use a Generic Repository." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Just do not use `Include` for this case. You have returned `IQueryable` - add needed `Include` later. Or there is project de pendency issues?

Comment: Problem solved, I will scrap the generic repository implementation and just use Include/ThenInclude as it should be normally done.